# VBA Excel: Macro-created graph with dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro where a graph is created with a dynamic range for the columns. Here is what I have so far.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

With Sheets("Sheet1")

    Charts.Add
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range("D2", Cells(2, N + 3))
    ActiveChart.Location xlLocationAsObject

End With

End Sub
```

Right now however, I keep encountering a run time error with the statement-

"The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type"

When I look in the code, it keeps referencing the last line.

```
ActiveChart.Location xlLocationAsObject
```

Any ideas? Thanks

**FOLLOW UP**

Here is the code referencing N

```
Dim N As Long
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
x = 0
y = 1

N = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter value", Type:=1)
If N > Columns.Count Then
    N = Columns.Count
Else
    For i = 4 To 9999
        Cells(1, i).ClearContents
        Cells(3, i).ClearContents
    Next i
End If

For i = 4 To N + 3
    x = x + y
    Cells(1, i) = x
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is N? What range of data are you planning to plot?

Comment: @Thinkingcap sorry totally spaced. Modified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[xlLocationAsObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195785(v=office.11).aspx) requires `where` parameter ,specifying  where you want the chart object to be embedded or placed

Replace

```
ActiveChart.Location xlLocationAsObject
```

with

```
ActiveChart.Location xlLocationAsObject, Name
```

to embed the chart in `Sheet1`

*See all available Options*
[image]